# How Do You Calculate Effort Force Required to Move a Load on a Gaffe Lever?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mathematics

First, I'd like to apologize for the misuse of any terms and my general ignorance- this is not my normal field.

The question revolves around mechanism of two levers with two pivots. There are two rods. Rod A will pivot around point *a*. The second rod, rod B, is attached to rod A at a pivot point, point *b*, that is a distance *x* from point *a* and a distance *y* from the opposite end of the rod A. Rod B has a distance *z* from the point *b* and the opposing side of rod B.

Point *a* is a fixed point, and the end of rod B would move linearly along an axis that is parallel to rod A in its current position.

The load force would be applied at the end of rod B, and the effort force would be applied at the end of rod A.

What formula would you use to calculate the required amount of effort needed to move the load?

I've included a quick draft below that hopefully clearly depicts my question.[image: Lever with two pivots]

After some searching, I've discovered some older crossbows used the "Gaffe Lever" that is nearly identical to the mechanism in question, however I couldn't find anything regarding calculating mechanical advantage for said lever.

Comment: If rod B stays vertical, it would be the same as if the load was sitting on Point b.

Comment: I wouldn't say it stays vertical. At the very least, the angle between rod A and rod B would change as rod A moved, and since rod B slides along a fixed axis. Though I should have mentioned said axis is parallel to rod A. I'll add that in.